# How to create custom Orb Tags for MVEL

Tags: mvel

I am using MVEL 2.x to do some email generation and was wondering if it is possible to create custom Orb tags. I've searched on stackoverflow and google but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

In order to add new Orb Tags to the compilation process of a template, you simply have to use `org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compileTemplate(String template, Map<String, Class> customNodes)`

`customNodes` maps orb tags name to node classes. E.g. `@encode{}` is an orb tag of name `encode`and will be handled by the custom node class `HtmlEncodingNode`.

To find more information on the subject, go directly to the code (to little doc). The `org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compileFrom` is where Orb Tags are being recognized.

Best regards,
Thim.